# Is it possible to replace a URL using regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Input text: `Our website is <a href="www.me.com">www.me.com</a>`

Output required: `Our website is <a href="[x]">[x]</a>`

Rule: any url needs to be replaced by [x]. URL might be with http/https or www or simply me.com. The solution needs to be case insensitive

```
$inputext = "<a href="www.me.com">www.me.com</a>"; 
$rule ="/(?<!a href=\")(?<!src=\")((http|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i";
$replacetext = "[X]";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo($outputext);
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Any url or those in `a` tags?

Comment: try `.*?"([^"]*)"\>(.*?)\<\/a\>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this to grab, `http/https` and with `www` or without `www` urls?

```
<?php
 $re = '/(https?:\/\/|(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?)/mi';
 $str = 'Our website is <a href="www.me.com">www.me.com</a>';
 $subst = '[x]';

 $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
 echo $result;
```

**Output:** `<a href="[x]">[x]</a>`

**Regex** https://regex101.com/r/X4vrOt/2

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/fFhOk

Comment: You're missing the protocol

Comment: @RobbieAverill woops, could you plz help me what I've missed? I'm really don't know what I've missed

Comment: See the question: "Rule: any url needs to be replaced by [x]. URL might be with http/https or www or simply me.com"

Comment: @RobbieAverill Ohh Yes Sir got it now, I'm going to edit my answer and fix that. Thanks :)

Comment: @RobbieAverill sir **Editted** my answer. Hope this will work with protocol now. Thanks for pointing out my error :)

Comment: Isn’t that going to replace every domain, not just the one in the question?

Comment: I would also add 'i' to the end to make it case insensitive. what say?

Answer (score 2):

Never parse HTML with regular expressions. It might seems like overkill to use a DOM parser for a job like this, but you're guaranteed to avoid problems at some point in the future.

```
$input = 'Our website is <a href="www.me.com">www.me.com</a>';
$replace = "[x]";

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($input, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a")->item(0);
$a->setAttribute("href", $replace);
$a->textContent = $replace;
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: But it would not work if the string does not contain anchor element.

Comment: Well your question provided sample input text, that's all I had to work with.